# Why does the transaction stay in queue from more than 240 second

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, truffle, quorum

I am running quorum nodes via the Quorum-maker script, and when trying to call functions from my already deployed smart contract, I get this error :

```
Transaction 0xe5f8c89e132ab29fa02702ea957318d7b45f788093086f1c452657c92f6e8f8c 
wasn't processed in 240 seconds!
```

I admit I am calling the function in a for loop over 250 times, but that isn't supposed to interfere with the queue, right?
My function call is just a simple adding of a person in a person mapping nothing complex. What can the problem be?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what gas price have you setted, and the state of the network, transactions can take up to several hours or days to be processed. Check https://ethgasstation.info/ for estimates on recomended gas price.

Comment: I run Quorum, There is no Gas in that. It uses QuorumChain as consensus.